# Program that will print all the numbers AND the sum of the numbers that have been printed so far in JS

Tags: javascript, printing, sum

Sum of Printed Numbers

Write a program that will print all the numbers from 1 to 135 AND the sum of the numbers that have been printed so far. Your output should look similar to this:

Number is: 0 Sum: 0

Number is: 1 Sum: 1

Number is: 2 Sum: 3

Number is: 3 Sum: 6

...

You are NOT allowed to use an array to solve this exercise.

I'm pretty new to JS, so i'm asking for help!

```
let num = 1;
let sum = 0;
let vob = 0

while(num != 135){
  sum = num + vob;
   console.log(num)
   vob = num
   num += 1
   console.log('Number is: ' + num + ' sum: ' + sum)
}
```

P.S this is what I did...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You are probably also not allowed to dump your homework at SO and let someone on the internet solve it for you. We would be glad to help you if you would show what you've done so far and at which point you could not get further.

Comment: let num = 1;
let sum = 0;
let vob = 0

while(num != 135){
    sum = num + vob;
    console.log(num)
    vob = num
    num += 1
    console.log('Number is: ' + num + ' sum: ' + sum)
}

Comment: @Emilis update your question with relevant code. And format it so we can read it.

Comment: I don't unterstand what `vob` is needed for. You can just add the number to the sum directly: `sum += num;`

Answer (score 1):

```
let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= 135; i++) {
  sum += i;
  console.log(`Number is: ${i}; Sum: ${sum}`);
}
```